# HTML Scraping the website with duplicated div class name

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, html-parser

I currently working on the HTML scraping the baka-update.
However, the name of Div Class is duplicated.

As my goal is as csv or json, I would like to use information in [sCat] as column name and [sContent] as to be get stored.....
Is their are way to scrape with this kinds of website?

Thanks,

Sample
https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=75363

Image 1
[image]
Image 2
[image]

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153558?')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#Get the name of the columns.... I hope
sCat = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sCat"]/text()')
#Get the actual data
sContent = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sContent"]/text()')

print('sCat: ', sCat)
print('sContent: ', sContent)
```

I tried but nothing I could find of
@Jasper Nichol M Fabella

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: First I try with the sCat, and sContent with picture two I just added.
It seems like I may get several information in the sContent but nothing I was able to get in sCat

Comment: Can you then add the code so far you have tried, in your question?

Comment: Just added! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to edit your code and got the following output. Maybe it will Help.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153558?')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
# print(page.content)

#Get the name of the columns.... I hope
sCat = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sCat"]')
#Get the actual data
sContent = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sContent"]')

print('sCat: ', len(sCat))
print('sContent: ', len(sContent))
json_dict={}

for i in  range(0,len(sCat)):
#     print(''.join(i.itertext()))
    sCat_text=(''.join(sCat[i].itertext()))
    sContent_text=(''.join(sContent[i].itertext()))
    json_dict[sCat_text]=sContent_text
print(json_dict)
```

I got the following output

[image]

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) expressions and create an absolute path on what you want to scrape

Comment: Thanks.
How should I do to make absolute path if their is duplicated name?

Comment: try this on your url . first inspect the element . then
press Ctrl + F. then type this 

//div[@class='Scat'][1]

Comment: I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to scrape?
If you are using BeautifulSoup? Then you can search for all content on the page with FindAll method with a class identifier and iterate thru that. You can the special "*_class*" deginator

Something like

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.source)
soup.find_all('div', class_='sCat')
# do rest of your logic work here
```

Edit: I was typing on my mobile on cached page before you made the edits. So didnt see the changes. Though i see you are using raw lxml library to parse. Yes that's faster but I am not to familiar, as Ive only used raw lxml library for one project but I think you can chain two search methods to distill to something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for help. Since I was doing on the coding without the background it was really hard for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `requests` and `lxml` library:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=75363')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

sCat = [i.text_content().strip() for i in tree.xpath('//div[@class="sCat"]')]
sContent = [i.text_content().strip() for i in tree.xpath('//div[@class="sContent"]')]
```

Comment: Glad I could help.